# Swift random number problems

Tags: xcode, random, swift, arc4random

I am using Swift with Xcode 6 Beta 5, and trying to generate a random number between my specific constraints.

Currently I am using the arc4random_uniform() function, which works for simple generating like:

```
arc4random_uniform(5)
```

But I am trying to create a random number with some complicated boundaries. This is my attempt:

```
randomMovement = Int( arc4random_uniform( (0.25 * Int(cs)) - ( 0.175 * rd ) ) ) + Int( 0.175 * rd )
```

cs and rd are both integers - initially, cs = 100, and rd = 40. This should generate a random number between 7 and 25. However, I run into many problems in Xcode with this, due to the variable types.

With this code, it initially shows the one error - On the first '*', it says:

```
'Int' is not convertible to 'UInt8'
```

But when I change that, it comes up with more problems, and it seems like I keep going round in a circle.

What's going wrong, and how can i fix this?

Comment: It seems there is a problem with type inference.  I broke it apart, and I'm getting a similar message with `NSNumber`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have type problems, build up your expression step by step.

```
import Darwin

let cs = 100
let rd = 40

let min = UInt32(0.175 * Float(rd))
let max = UInt32(0.25 * Float(cs))

// This isn't really necessary, the next line will crash if it's not true, but
// just calling out this implicit assumption
assert(max >= min)

let randomMovement = Int(arc4random_uniform(max - min) + min)
```

`arc4random_uniform` takes a `UInt32`, so you need to get there. You can't multiply `Float` and `Int` without a typecast, so you need to add those.

When I say "build up step-by-step" I mean for you, not the compiler. The compiler can handle:

```
let randomMovement = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(0.25 * Float(cs)) - UInt32(0.175 * Float(rd))) + UInt32(0.25 * Float(cs)))
```

but it's a bit hard to understand (and may compute cs/4 twice).

Comment: The assertion isn't so unnecessary if negative numbers can get in the way.

Comment: I just mean that "max-min" in the next line will crash anyway (since Swift does range checking), so the assertion is just moving the crash up one line.

Comment: Minor caveat for anyone dealing with big numbers: be careful when casting the results of arc4random (unsigned 32-bit) to Int (signed 32-bit on 32-bit architectures.) e.g. the above code will compile but crash at runtime if min = 2147483647 and max = 2147483747 on 32-bit platforms, but work fine on 64.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built in random() function in swift:

```
let randomInt = random() % 5
```

Answer (score 1):

in **Swift 4.2** you can make something like:

```
let number = Int.random(in: 0 ..< 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

With **Swift 4.2**, you can now call directly from [`Int.random`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2995648-random). You can see more details [here](https://learningswift.brightdigit.com/swift-4-2-random-changes-wwdc-2018/).

Answer (score -1):

```
let min  = a
let max = b

var x =  min + random_uniform(max - min)
```